Performance issues merging tables from different databases and different datatypes
This is my first question here, so sorry if i don't do it properly. Also, i'm not an expert on Oracle or DBM, just a developer with a performance problem.
I'm working with an Oracle environment where we have 2 different databases
Database 1 (DB1) has 1 user wh1 with a table called lotxlocxid
Database 2 (DB2) has 5 different users, each one has their own lotxlocxid table (wmwhse1, wmwhse2, etc)
On our legacy front-end, we have to display the content of all the lotxlocxid tables, from both databases.
The main problem is that the tables from Database2 have most of their fields are nvarchar2, and in Database1 the same fields are in varchar2 so, if we try to join them , we have to cast the fields to varchar2(x) to avoid the ORA-12704 error and that causes the second problem, if we "cast" all the fields, the indexes are not being used properly, so the performance of the query is poor.
I've been checking the Explain Plan in PLSQL and see some full scans, i've tried to add new indexes with the cast fields, but still seems to
Our main query (with some other tables), encapsulated in a view, looks like this
create or replace view wh1.v_dmt_lotxlocxid as
select 'DMT' as datasource, cast(wh.facility as varchar2(5)) as facility, to_char(lli.lot) as lot, cast(l.loc as varchar2(10)) as loc, cast(lli.id as varchar2(50)) as id, cast(lli.storerkey as varchar2(15)) as storerkey, CAST(lli.sku AS varchar2(50)) as sku,
       lli.qty, lli.qtyallocated, lli.qtypicked, lli.qtyexpected, cast(lli.status as varchar2(10)) as status,
       to_char(l.locationtype) as locationtype, to_char(l.putawayzone) putawayzone,
       lli.editdate, lli.adddate, cast(lli.editwho as varchar2(50)) as editwho, cast(lli.addwho as varchar2(50)) as addwho, wh.externalwh
       from wmwhse1.lotxlocxid@sce lli, wmwhse1.loc@sce l, dmt.warehouse wh
       where lli.loc = l.loc
         and l.whseid = wh.whseid
union
select 'DMT' as datasource, cast(wh.facility as varchar2(5)) as facility, to_char(lli.lot) as lot, cast(l.loc as varchar2(10)) as loc, cast(lli.id as varchar2(50)) as id, cast(lli.storerkey as varchar2(15)) as storerkey, CAST(lli.sku AS varchar2(50)) as sku,
       lli.qty, lli.qtyallocated, lli.qtypicked, lli.qtyexpected, cast(lli.status as varchar2(10)) as status,
       to_char(l.locationtype) as locationtype, to_char(l.putawayzone) putawayzone,
       lli.editdate,lli.adddate, cast(lli.editwho as varchar2(50)) as editwho,  cast(lli.addwho as varchar2(50)) as addwho, wh.externalwh
       from wmwhse2.lotxlocxid@sce lli, wmwhse2.loc@sce l, dmt.warehouse wh
       where lli.loc = l.loc
         and l.whseid = wh.whseid
union
select 'DMT' as datasource, cast(wh.facility as varchar2(5)) as facility, to_char(lli.lot) as lot, cast(l.loc as varchar2(10)) as loc, cast(lli.id as varchar2(50)) as id, cast(lli.storerkey as varchar2(15)) as storerkey, CAST(lli.sku AS varchar2(50)) as sku,
       lli.qty, lli.qtyallocated, lli.qtypicked, lli.qtyexpected, cast(lli.status as varchar2(10)) as status,
       to_char(l.locationtype) as locationtype, to_char(l.putawayzone) putawayzone,
       lli.editdate,lli.adddate, cast(lli.editwho as varchar2(50)) as editwho,  cast(lli.addwho as varchar2(50)) as addwho, wh.externalwh
       from wmwhse3.lotxlocxid@sce lli, wmwhse3.loc@sce l, dmt.warehouse wh
       where lli.loc = l.loc
         and l.whseid = wh.whseid
union
select 'DMT' as datasource, cast(wh.facility as varchar2(5)) as facility, to_char(lli.lot) as lot, cast(l.loc as varchar2(10)) as loc, cast(lli.id as varchar2(50)) as id, cast(lli.storerkey as varchar2(15)) as storerkey, CAST(lli.sku AS varchar2(50)) as sku,
       lli.qty, lli.qtyallocated, lli.qtypicked, lli.qtyexpected, cast(lli.status as varchar2(10)) as status,
       to_char(l.locationtype) as locationtype, to_char(l.putawayzone) putawayzone,
       lli.editdate,lli.adddate, cast(lli.editwho as varchar2(50)) as editwho,  cast(lli.addwho as varchar2(50)) as addwho, wh.externalwh
       from wmwhse4.lotxlocxid@sce lli, wmwhse4.loc@sce l, dmt.warehouse wh
       where lli.loc = l.loc
         and l.whseid = wh.whseid
union
select 'DMT' as datasource, cast(wh.facility as varchar2(5)) as facility, to_char(lli.lot) as lot, cast(l.loc as varchar2(10)) as loc, cast(lli.id as varchar2(50)) as id, cast(lli.storerkey as varchar2(15)) as storerkey, CAST(lli.sku AS varchar2(50)) as sku,
       lli.qty, lli.qtyallocated, lli.qtypicked, lli.qtyexpected, cast(lli.status as varchar2(10)) as status,
       to_char(l.locationtype) as locationtype, to_char(l.putawayzone) putawayzone,
       lli.editdate,lli.adddate, cast(lli.editwho as varchar2(50)) as editwho,  cast(lli.addwho as varchar2(50)) as addwho, wh.externalwh
       from wmwhse5.lotxlocxid@sce lli, wmwhse5.loc@sce l, dmt.warehouse wh
       where lli.loc = l.loc
         and l.whseid = wh.whseid
union
select 'LEGACY' as datasource, l.facility, lli.lot, l.loc, lli.id, lli.storerkey, lli.sku, lli.qty,
       lli.qtyallocated, lli.qtypicked, lli.qtyexpected, lli.status,
       l.locationtype, l.putawayzone,
       lli.editdate,lli.adddate, lli.editwho, lli.addwho,
       (select wh.externalwh from dmt.warehouse wh where cast(wh.facility as varchar2(5)) = l.facility) as externalwh
       from wh1.lotxlocxid lli, wh1.loc l
       where lli.loc = l.loc
;

I've reading a lot of literature about Materialized views, but as far as i know, i can not create a MV on DB1 using dblink to DB2. This problem can be applied to other querys that we're using.
Also, data will be accessed live, so syncing the data from DB2 into DB1 should be done constantly
Thank you very much
I've tried indexing all the possible fields, reading posts about materialized views without success. I expect to get a method to join tables from different databases without performance problems.

Can you edit your question to include a typical query on the view, please?

Your question is too generic - "most fields are nvarchar2" needs to be more specific. Provide a specific column and its datatype on both sides of a specific join in a specific query, as simplified as possible. Also, a view in and of itself has no performance significance, because a view isn't a query (it doesn't execute all by itself), but a query block intended to be used by a higher level query (the SQL hitting the view). One can only consider the performance when seeing this top-level query against the view, not the view in isolation.

You would also need to provide the execution plans of a performant query without the cast, and a non-performant one with the cast. It could be that you need function-based indexes with gathered stats, or that Oracle cannot rightly guess the cardinality of the join through the function and so is opting for a different join method or the join order is changed, etc.. many possibilities. The plans will tell you what has changed, at which point you can then ask the question why the new plan is inferior and where it is going wrong.

Have you tried UNION ALL in place of UNION? UNION removes duplicates, which is not free.
